# Optimizing site

Tags: plugins

So, I have about 10 plugins.

They all have their own js and css files. However I also customized the site and not much of css and js are used.

Is there a way for me to clean these up and consolidate them into few files?

Thanks

Comment: You can remove a registered script with [`wp_deregister_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) function.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com). In this way your website will load (at least) 30% faster and will also be secured. Cloudflare is a cloud proxy. All website traffic will be handled by this service. There is a free service that really works. If you want, you can also try paid services, but the free one is a good start.
2. You can use a wordpress plugin like [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) or Wp Total Cache. For more details, see the [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=cache) page.
3. Search on Google for "wordpress combine js and css". There are tutorials and scripts for doing this. It will help you to decrease the website load time.

Conclusions

- Option 1) includes options 2) and 3)
- Option 2) includes option 3)

I will suggest you to try cloudflare. Too many plugins is not a solution for your website.

Comment: 100 well written plugins is better than one poorly written one :-)

Comment: Do you know how slow is the admin panel of a websites with so many plugins? Trust me, it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

Based in my experience, I think that the [Better WordPress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) plugin do the best job in minifying and combining js and css.

Answer (score 0):

You can minify your files so they will be a smaller size.  You can also combine your CSS and JS files so they load in fewer files which makes less requests.  This will speed things up significantly.  There is some plugins in the WordPress.org plugin directory and 3rd parties who help with this.